# Auto set "Not Allowed" cursor for disabled fields in reactive form

Tags: angular, css, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Is there anyway in Angular 6/7 that

when I hover over any disabled field of the reactive form then the cursor 
 automatically change to "Not Allowed"???

I don't want to use CSS to change the cursor. There has to be some way to do it with angular only.

PS: currently control is getting disabled but the cursor is not being changed to "NotAllowed".

Answer (score 1):

```
input:disabled,
input[disabled]{
cursor:not-allowed !important;
}

select:disabled,
select[disabled]
{
cursor:not-allowed !important;
}
textarea:disabled,
textarea[disabled]
{
cursor:not-allowed !important;
}


  Although I had to use CSS, This fixed my issue in a very clear way.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this and also get rid of the `!important` by using the following code:

```css
mat-form-field:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```